# passing environment variables from docker-compose file to python container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm running a Python app, and I want to dockerize it.
I have environment variables to pass to the program,
but I don't manage to do it in docker.

my demo app (main.py):

```
import os

print(os.environ.get('MY_VARIABLE', 'NO VARIABLE IN ENVIRONMENT'))
```

Docker file :

```
FROM python:3.10-slim AS BASE

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: my_app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - MY_VARIABLE=my_value
```

output of running the created image :

```
2024-01-10 13:22:29 NO VARIABLE IN ENVIRONMENT
```

the environment variable did not get its value from the docker-compose file.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you've shared works for me

Comment: What command are you using to run it?  The basic structure of what you've shown seems fine.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm a running docker-compose up. then go to the Docker desktop app  and press the run button on the image

Comment: Make sure you build the latest image `docker compose up --build`

Comment: @Paolo here's what I noticed: if I run ```docker-compose up``` (with or without ```--build```) the command also runs the container, and prints the expected value. however, if I then use ```docker run``` to create a container from the image, it does not find ```MY_VARIABLE```.

Comment: for `docker run ` you shall manually pass the environment variable via the cmd line as docker deamon doesn't refer to the compose file while creating the container directly using the image

Comment: @KayvanShah oh I see, I thought the environment variables were already included in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you describe two ways of running the container:

> I'm running `docker-compose up`.

This should work as you expect.  If you run `docker-compose up` without a `-d` option, you should see the configured `my_value` appear as the container's output, and `docker-compose logs myapp` should show it as well.

> Go to the Docker Desktop app and press the run button on the image.

This just runs the image, without any particular configuration.  It is the same as `docker run your-image`, without mentioning Compose.  This path ignores anything in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

> I thought the environment variables were already included in the image.

The only things in the image are what's described in the Dockerfile, possibly as modified by the Compose file's `build:` block.  If the Compose file contains `environment:` settings (or `env_file:`), or overrides the `command:`, or has other settings, these are *not* included in the image.

This means another way to get consistent behavior here is to include the environment value in the Dockerfile

```bash
ENV MY_VARIABLE=my_value
```

This doesn't stop you from overriding that value when you run a container, either from a `docker run -e` option or Compose `environment:`.  Those values will take precedence over anything configured in a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an environment file `.env` at the same level as `docker-compose` file

```bash
version: '3.7'

services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: my_app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    env_file:
      - .env
```

It is a good practice to have all your environment variables in one environment variables file (`.env`) instead of writing them one by one in the compose file.

```bash
MY_VARIABLE=my_value
```

If you want to run create a new container while passing env variables via `.env` file using `docker run` command

```
docker run --env-file=.env your_image_name
```